# Using <object> to embed content on blogs, need to resize <object> element according to content inside

Tags: javascript, object, iframe, embed

I am working on a project in which users upload photos. They are then given an embed code that they can place in their blog posts. This uses the object tag and fills it with content from our server. The problem I am having is that the content is larger than the object tag, and is getting cut off. I need to take the height and width of the image loaded inside the object tag and change the height and width of the object tag to match.

My problem is this:
 - When I run some JS in the console it cannot see any elements inside the object tag
 - The object loads a file from our server, in that file I have included some JS, but it is not able to see the object tag it is being loaded into.

Anyone have any advice here?